# Windows Server 2008 R2 only boots to Recovery Console

Tags: boot, windows-server-2008-r2

I was bringing up a server this morning, and all it will do is boot to the recovery agent, giving the following options:

Restore a backup image, Memory Check, Command Prompt, shutdown, restart.

The strange thing is that there is a problem with the Server 2008 R2 installation on partition G: Windows is installed on C:, not G:, so where it gets that from, I have no idea.

I have tried rebooting the system several times etc, checked the boot order in the BIOS, run `chkdsk` on C: and G: (no errors found).

Otherwise, the only changes made were installations and configurations of Team Server and SQL Server the previous day (from which their installers were on partition G:.

I have tried removing all other hard drives (this now means that the windows installation is on D: and system reserved on c:.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Same problem here, after unplugging (not shutting down properly) the server.

Comment: In the end, I put it down to a mixture of things, including problems with Windows Software RAID, power loss, and a surge within my UPS.